# cursor and combining diacritics in shell

Tags: bash, shell, osx, unicode, user-interface

I frequently deal with combining diacritics, especially the combining acute accent (U0301, or `\xcc\x81`). I have a keyboard set up to insert this character, and that works fine in the shell.

```
$ echo а́
> а́

$ echo а́ | hexdump
> 0000000 d0 b0 cc 81 0a
> 0000005
```

However, the user interface is confused about how many characters are present. If I press the arrow up button and then try to edit a command that includes combining diacritics in the arguments, then I always end up deleting the wrong characters and inserting characters in the wrong place. For example, if I press backspace once, then the shell shows that I have deleted `а́`, but pressing `Return` shows that I have only deleted the diacritic.

```
$ echo 
> а
```

Pressing the up arrow again shows what was actually interpreted:

```
$ echo а
```

Is it possible to get the shell to treat combining diacritics as truly combined with the previous letter, so that a backspace will delete both? Alternatively, I would be happy for the shell to display the combining diacritic separately, something like `а'`?

Comment: Try with a newer version of `bash`/`readline`. It works for me (Debian's 4.3.39, backspace deletes both characters (the glyph) for e' and arrows jump over the combined glyph). Zsh (5.0.8) displays 0-width characters as `<0301>` in reverse video.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the suggestions! I already have `zsh` 4.3.11 installed, so I tried that out and it works just fine. If I were dealing with more than one kind of diacritic, then I'm sure I would prefer to have them actually rendered, but since I am just working with one most of the time, having the block code is just fine. I am very happy to have a working solution. I'll just switch over to `zsh` whenever I need to work with diacritics. Thanks!!!